# Vertical spacing in fraction

Tags: fractions

How can I even out the spacing in these fraction?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\frac{8}{4}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is really the choice of the font designer.  Thus, your primary method of dealing with this issue is to choose a new font.

Comment: For example, what font can I use? @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: Since this is not an issue that bothers me, I haven't really looked for a "fix".  But, for example, `\usepackage{fourier}` provides a different math (and text) font in which the fraction line seems more equally spaced.

Comment: @cufcuf - Be *very careful* regarding what you ask for. Do you really want the numerator and denominator terms in `\[ \frac{8}{4} \frac{y}{x} \frac{u}{h} \frac{\int f(x)\,dx}{\sum_i v_i} \]` be placed at different heights, depending solely on what's in a given `\frac` expression? That would violate just about every known rule of fine math typesetting...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wondered :) @Mico

Comment: hmm. thank you @StevenB.Segletes